# Recursively remove all invalid characters from text files in place

Tags: terminal, command-line, utf-8

I have several thousand text files, some of which contain invalid UTF-8 characters. I want to recursively remove all invalid characters from these files in place.

I am aware that many similar questions have been asked before, such as: [how to remove non UTF-8 characters from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999651/how-to-remove-non-utf-8-characters-from-text-file) but I have not found one that is both recursive and operates in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The great thing about UNIX commands is that you can combine them together. `iconv` doesn't know how to recurse into directories, but `find` does. It can call `iconv` on every file it sees.

(These commands will convert all files in the current directory and *all* directories within. Make sure you are in the directory you want to convert all files in recursively.)

To change all files with the extension `.txt`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename; do 
        iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c "$filename" > "$filename".iconv_cleaned_utf8
        mv "$filename".iconv_cleaned_utf8 "$filename"
    done
```

I suppose this code requires some explanation. What it does is:

- `find` prints out all the filenames of the files involved, separated by a null byte (the null byte is the only invalid character for a file path)
- bash `read`s the filenames and loops through them
- `iconv` converts the file to a tempfile with an extra extension
- we `mv` the tempfile to replace the original file.

If they have different extensions (this is for any and all files under the current directory), remove the `-name *.txt`

It's a bit cleaner if you have the `sponge` utility from `moreutils`, but that is not installed by default.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename; do 
        iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c "$filename" | sponge "$filename"
    done
```

Comment: Thanks @0942v8653, I ran your command, there was lots of output to the terminal, however there were no edits to files I know to contain illegal characters.

Comment: Ooh, sorry, I didn't actually test it yet, it turns out iconv writes to the terminal. Will update my answer.

Comment: @pingu: edited.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer the whole question but I have been a happy user of BBEdit for quite a number of years (Pre-OSX at least...). I use it for HTML hacking and occasional opening of files that I can't figure out.

It has this nice feature called Zap Gremlins, which basically removes a whole bunch of strange and non-ASCII characters from any file. Which sounds a lot like what you need to do.

AND it is massively scriptable, but not free. It may be [worth investigating](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) to see if it will do what you want.

Comment: [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (the free variant of BBEdit) has the same feature.